# What would be the best approach to include multiple labels or textfields in a view?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I need to create a view controller with multiple `UILabel` or `UIbutton` (about 20), that open an alert box with an input `UITextField` on touch. What would be the best approach to do this?

Also, if adding them in a `UIScrollView` is appropriate, since I won't be able to place all 20 in the storyboard view, how can one make outlet connections to each one of them?

Comment: This question is pretty broad and vague - if you give a bit more information about how you want to set your UI up, you can get better suggestions.

Comment: u can also use collectionview >>>>

Comment: I understand, but think of it as a form with about 20 buttons, that on click open an alert box to take user inputs.

Comment: Below see my updated answer.

Answer (score 5):

You should use a table view instead. If you have only 20 such items then you can create them in storyboard itself using static table view cells.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give this a go!

Comment: Thanks Pradeep.You gave us short solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you know something that is going to be repeated some `n times`, then the best way to add them to the view is by using the UITableView (for vertical views) or UICollectionView (for grid-like views), however, if the items are different and non-repetitive, the best possible case to display them is by using UIScrollView. You add a UIView with scrollView as its child.

Afterwards, you can add more child views in the UIScrollView and increase the dimensions of the Scrollview as soon as more items start to add in it. To increase the ScrollView height or say width, or both, you use `contentSize` with `viewWillLayoutSubviews()`. The structure may look like this:

```
View
--UIScrollView
---UILabel1
---UIImageView
---UITextView
---UIButton
```

For creating the layout, there are couple of ways: 
1. You set `simulated size` under `size inspector` to `Freeform` with the choice of height and width, then add subViews such as UITextView, UILabel and so on. 
2. You programmatically add UIScrollView and then other views as subviews of the scroll.

Hope it helps in making you the right choice.

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed info! If I follow either of the two layout processes you've mentioned, how will I make my outlet connections? Will I be able to see all of my buttons or lables in the story board?

Comment: Suppose you have created a view say: `let myImage = UIImageView()` - This thing is equivalent to your outlet, you then give this declaration a frame, and add it as a subview like this: `self.yourView.addSubview(myImage)`. For creating actions it is almost the same, but only thing you need to do is mention the function to be called like this: `let myButton = UIButton()` 
and call the function like this: `myButton.addTarget(self, action: "nameOfYourFunc", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)`

Answer (score 1):

As Pradeep give you the idea for you solution very simply, I tried and I got it.I posted the answer below.It works fine.

OBJECTIVE C

ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()<UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate>
{
   NSMutableArray *array;
}
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableViewData;

@end

@implementation ViewController

@synthesize tableViewData;
- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
   array = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"iOS",@"Android",@"Windows",@"Blackberry",@"iPad",@"iPod",@"iWatch",@"iTV",@"iPhone",@"Tablet",@"Lenova",@"Microsoft",@"Honor",@"Samsung",@"Mi4",@"Moto",@"Lava",@"Nokia",@"ASus",@"OnePlus", nil];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

//UITableView DataSource methods
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
  return 1;
}
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
   return array.count;
}
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  static NSString *strCell = @"cell";
  UITableViewCell *cell =  [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:strCell];
  if(cell==nil)
  {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:strCell];
  }
  cell.textLabel.text = array[indexPath.row];
  return cell;
}

//UITableView Delegates Methods
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Input" message:@"TextField" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
   [alertController addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler:^(UITextField *textField)
   {
     textField.placeholder = NSLocalizedString(@"Enter the Product Name", @"Login");
     textField.text = array[indexPath.row];
   }];
    [alertController addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler:^(UITextField *textField)
    {
     textField.placeholder = NSLocalizedString(@"Enter the Password", @"Password");
     textField.secureTextEntry = YES;
    }];
   UIAlertAction* ok = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:nil];
   [alertController addAction:ok];
   [self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
@end
```

SWIFT

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet var tableViewData: UITableView!

var array : [String] = ["iOS","Android","Windows","Blackberry","iPad","iPod","iWatch","iTV","iPhone","Tablet","Lenova","Microsoft","Honor","Samsung","Mi4","Moto","Lava","Nokia","ASus","OnePlus"]
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return array.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CELL") as UITableViewCell?

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Value1, reuseIdentifier: "CELL")
    }

    cell?.textLabel?.text = array[indexPath.row] as String
    return cell!
}
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
{

    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Input", message: "TextField", preferredStyle: .Alert)
    var loginTextField: UITextField?
    alertController.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler { (textField) -> Void in
        // Enter the textfiled customization code here.
        loginTextField = textField
        loginTextField?.placeholder = "Enter the product"
        loginTextField?.text = self.array[indexPath.row]
    }
    let defaultAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default, handler: nil)
    alertController.addAction(defaultAction)

    presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
}
```

Comment: See the Updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 general approaches.

1. ScrollView.
2. TableView.
3. StackView (Only iOS 9)

**ScrollView**

See [Fennec](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35666597/3857417)'s answer.

**TableView**

There are two approaches to TableViews: `Static` and `Dynamic`.
If you're always sure there are 20 buttons/labels you can use static TableViews and you won't face the problem you mentioned about scrollViews in IB (because tableViews are scrollable in IB). But if you're not sure that there are always 20 buttons/labels, it's better to use Dynamic tableViews. [user3182143](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3182143/user3182143)'s answer covers that up.

**StackView**

See this tutorial -> [Introducing Stack Views](http://www.raywenderlich.com/114552/uistackview-tutorial-introducing-stack-views)

But if it was me, I would have gone with the Dynamic TableView.